# How can I open chrome and do a google image search from a node/electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, electron

I'm trying to integrate google image search into my electron based photos app. I want users to click on an option to "Search google for image" and this will in turn open up chrome (if available) with the local image file in question and then do a google image search from there. If chrome is not available on the system then I can always show an alert saying this feature only works with google chrome installed.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!

By using Electron's `shell.openExternal` function like this:

```
const { shell } = require('electron');

shell.openExternal('https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+search+here')
```

This opens the given link in the user's default browser.

[`openExternal` Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenexternalurl-options)